# phpbb check that user is logged in on custom php page

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm running a private phpbb 3.0.12 forum and linking to a page called videochat.php which has a flash page connected to a rtmfp server. I would like to ensure that the person visiting videochat.php is logged in and registered (any access level besides guest) else it redirects them to www.domain.com. If the Member is registered I would like a variable called $videochatusername set. Thanks!

videochat.php is (linked from the forum to this page) ->    domain.com/forum/videochat.php
forum root dir -> domain.com/forum/

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '/forum';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.'.$phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);

if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
{
echo('NOT LOGGEDIN');
}
else{
include($phpbb_root_path.'config.'.$phpEx);

// test echo
echo $user->data['username'];

?>
```

Comment: updated sorry i had issues formatting the post

Comment: Please do not deface your post like that. I have rolled it back. If you no longer need help you can delete the post.

Comment: Hey, man, don't give up :) Now the question is ok +1! For your next question make sure to read [ask]. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In phpBB 3.3.2:

```html
<!-- IF S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
     ...do something...
     ...you can even run php by this...
<!-- ELSE -->
     ...if user is not logged in...
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

EDIT:
To run php you need to enable it in admin settings

```html
<!-- IF S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
     ...do something...
     <!-- PHP -->
          ...php code...
     <!-- ENDPHP -->

<!-- ELSE -->
     ...if user is not logged in...
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to functional. Try this:

```
if ($user->data['username'] == 'Anonymous')
{
    // User is not logged in/registered
    // Your redirect code can go here if you haven't output anything to the browser
}
```

The difference is that `'Anonymous'` is surrounded by quotes and not a constant, like your code has.

If you add an `else` block to this `if`, you can set your `$videochatusername` variable

```
else
{
    $videochatusername = $user->data['username'];
}
```